# Two missing numbers

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Two numbers go at the $?$s, what are they and why?

> $733,\space \space 716,\space \space 645,\space \space 565,\space \space 324,\space \space 276,\space \space 77,\space \space 75,\space \space 64,\space \space 56,\space \space ?,\space \space ?$

Hints

> As noted in the comments these are the final two numbers in the sequence.
>
>  The sequence is strictly decreasing and contains only positive integers
>  (that narrows them down to $1485$ choices).
>
>  We could extend the sequence to the left using the same logic, but there are many ways to do so.

Comment: Does the sequence continue after the second **?** ?

Comment: They are the final two in this sequence.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Are there enough clues given to identify the missing numbers?

Comment: @Techidiot I believe so.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Time for a hint?

Comment: @Techidiot I thought this would be solved pretty quickly!

Comment: @JonathanAllan I have tried binary/hex/word values/differences/multiplications and everything but nothing seem to fit. The set is of finite 12 so may be something related to a group of 12. Which gives months/zodiac signs

Comment: Interesting that only the digits 1-7 show up. Maybe there's something there?

Comment: Your hint says, that if we want to extend the list to the left, there is ambiguity in which number comes next. Let's say we erase 733 on the left. Can it be substituted with another number as well, i.e. does this ambiguity appear in the already shown part of the sequence as well?

Comment: @elias - the ambiguity is ripe in the sequence as written, one could make the logical reasoning stricter and then the puzzle would not be worth asking as the answer would probably be [oeis.org/A...](http://oeis.org).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sequence is:

> 733,  716,  645,  565,  324,  276,  77,  75,  64,  56,  **7,  4**

Because:

> The sequence consists of digits 1-7 and each digit **x** occurs **x** times. There is one 1, two 2s, three 3s, three 4s, five 5s, six 6s, six 7s. The next two numbers should have a 7 and a 4 in them to complete the pattern. Since the sequence is strictly decreasing, the last two numbers are **7,4**.

Comment: Oh darn! How bad of me to not see that. +1

Comment: Enthusiastic ^vote with a note: Care to mention in the answer how you realized this?

Answer (score 2):

Since I have spent quiet a few days on this one, needed to post something I finally got working(at least in my own head)

**The Mystery Sequence is**

> $733,\space \space 716,\space \space 645,\space \space 565,\space \space 324,\space \space 276,\space \space 77,\space \space 75,\space \space 64,\space \space 56,\space \space 48,\space \space 38$

Pattern is

> We need to take the sum of all the digits which leads to *13 14 15 16 9 15 14 13 10 11* Now, lets place them vertically to see how they look. When done, we can see the following sequence -
>  .
>  .
>  .
>  .
>  13 *(Set n-2)*
>  14 *(Set n-2)*    $\Leftarrow$    DESCENDING ORDER
>  15 *(Set n-2)*
>  16 *(Set n-2)*
>      **-> 9** *(Set n-2 begins)*
>  15 *(Set n-1)*
>  14 *(Set n-1)*  $\Leftarrow$     ASCENDING ORDER
>  12 *(Set n-1)*
>      **-> 10** *(Set n-1 begins)*
>  11 *(Set n)*
>  12 *(Set n)*      $\Leftarrow$ DESCENDING ORDER
>      **-> 11** *(Set n begins)*   **BEGIN HERE**   $\Uparrow$
>
>  Which means we need two numbers whose sum gives 12 and 11. For 12, the next number we have is 48 and for 11, the next number we have is 38. Since, I am assuming **->** to be the start, there cannot be any numbers beyond that. I am not good at formatting and I suck at mathematical formatting so bear with me on this... Well, I am satisfied with that thing above :)

Comment: Pretty amazing find, but more complicated reasoning than the expected solution.

Comment: Well, this is amazing, but the sum of digits in 75 is not 13, but 12, and this fact breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

The two numbers are clearly 37224 and 342283.

This is because these are the values of the 9th-degree polynomial

> $$\frac{3923 x^9}{72576} - \frac{53903 x^8}{20160} + \frac{3423661 x^7}{60480} - \frac{321713 x^6}{480} + \frac{84048523 x^5}{17280} - \frac{21394487 x^4}{960} + \frac{5800232051 x^3}{90720} - \frac{552402481 x^2}{5040} + \frac{126557399 x}{1260} - 36003$$

evaluated at x = 1...10. So the next two numbers are this polynomial evaluated at x = 11 and x = 12.

Comment: Much as I love a polynomial fit with more inputs than the sequence, I'm afraid it's much more logical. You'll know the answer is right when you have it.

Comment: y = 23.34446 + (723.1129 - 23.34446)/(1 + (x/4.927903)^4.959924),,36 and 32

Comment: polynomial answers are not appropriate answers for this kind of questions in my opinion.

Comment: I think it was just a joke.

Comment: Yes, this is primarily a joke answer. But this is the polynomial fit with least degree. This is partially why I hate sequence puzzles.

Comment: My ^vote was a joke vote