# Sum self enumerated digits

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

Please fill in the
entire summations for lines 4 through 9
and just the total for line 1,000,000.

1.     
 1     =   **1**

       
 2.    
 14    =   **2** + **12**

       
 3.    
 41    =   **2** + **3** + **13** + **23**

       
 4.    
 ?     =   ? + ? + ? + . . .

       
 5.    
 ?     =   ? + ? + ? + . . .

       
 6.    
 ?     =   ? + ? + ? + . . .

       
 7.    
 ?     =   ? + ? + ? + . . .

       
 8.    
 ?     =   ? + ? + ? + . . .

       
 9.    
 ?     =   ? + ? + ? + . . .

    
1,000,000.   
 ?     =   (no need for the series of terms
                      if you’re not in the mood)

The right side of each summation
produces the **minimum possible total** from
a series of **unique numbers** whose digits include
     one **1**,
     two **2**s,
   three **3**s, and so on up to the line’s number.
 
Here are two straightforward approaches
that produce non-minimal totals,
as less than 111 is possible
for line 4.

<del>4.</del>         
111   =   **1** + **2** + **3** + **4** + **23** + **34** + **44**

<del>4.</del>     
223334445   =   **1** + **223334444**

Beyond line 9,
digits equivalent to **10** and more are in play
for the summed terms, but digit positions
have powers- of-10 values as usual.
 
Nothing here requires actual depiction of
digits greater than **9**
but, to clarify, a non-minimal line 10 might use
**[10]** to represent the digit **10** like this.

10. 122333444455555666666777777788888900111111109
      =

               
    **122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999**

            
      +   **[10][10][10][10][10][10][10][10][10][10]**

=  
**122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999**

            
+ **10**×1000000000
+ **10**×100000000
+ **10**×10000000
+ **10**×1000000

            
+ **10**×100000
+ **10**×10000
+ **10**×1000
+ **10**×100
+ **10**×10
+ **10**

=  
122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999
                                + 11111111110

[no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) solutions should receive more approval
than computed solutions,
which would have value nonetheless as cross checks.

<sub>This puzzle was motivated by
[*Two missing numbers*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49068/two-missing-numbers).</sub>

Comment: "*whose digits include one 1, two 2s, three 3s, and so on up to the row’s number*" - what does this mean when the row's number is greater than 9?

Comment: So couldn't you lower your "score" by choosing a different base? That doesn't really make sense...

Comment: (eg if the second row were expressed in base 3, then the sum would only be $21_3$, or 7)

Comment: Better now, hopes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We proceed by induction.

In row $n$, all the digits $n$ should appear as units digits, not tens or hundreds digits. So we have $n+1n+2n+3n+\dots$ as part of the sum. This uses up all the digits $n$ and one of each of $1,2,3,\dots,n-1$, leaving still to be allotted a total of $k-1$ digits $k$ for every $k$ from $2$ up to $n-1$. These remaining digits should then be arranged in exactly the same way as in the $(n-2)$th row but with each digit incremented by $1$. Let's see how this works in practice:

4. > $4+14+24+34$ plus ($2+12$ incremented by one) gives $3+23+4+14+24+34$.
5. > $5+15+25+35+45$ plus ($2+3+13+23$ incremented by one) gives $3+4+24+34+5+15+25+35+45$.

So the $n$th row has one more one-digit number, and $n-1$ more two-digit numbers, than the $(n-1)$th. Thus, by induction:

- for $n=2k$ the $n$th row has $k$ one-digit numbers and $k^2$ two-digit numbers;
- for $n=2k-1$ the $n$th row has $k$ one-digit numbers and $k(k-1)$ two-digit numbers.

And by induction again, we can compute the sum $S_n$ of the $n$th row as follows:

- if $n=2k$, then \begin{align} S_n&=n+1n+2n+\dots+(n-1)n+(S_{n-2}\text{ incremented by $1$}) \\&=n^2+10\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+S_{n-2}+(k-1)+11(k-1)^2 \\&=S_{n-2}+4k^2+10k(2k-1)+(k-1)(11k-10) \\&=S_{n-2}+35k^2-31k+10\end{align}
- if $n=2k-1$, then \begin{align} S_n&=n+1n+2n+\dots+(n-1)n+(S_{n-2}\text{ incremented by $1$}) \\&=n^2+10\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+S_{n-2}+(k-1)+11(k-1)(k-2) \\&=S_{n-2}+(2k-1)^2+10(k-1)(2k-1)+(k-1)(11k-21) \\&=S_{n-2}+35k^2-66k+32\end{align}

Now we have inductive formulae for the solution, which will simplify in order to give reasonably straightforward formulae which are cubic in $k$, and possibly even a unified formula depending only on $n$. As shown in [this CW answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49882/5373) from the OP, the sum for $n=1,000,000$ is

> $S_{1,000,000}=1,458,333,833,333,500,000$

(I haven't checked the details of this derivation, but I trust humn to get it right).

Comment: For $n=3=2\cdot 2-1$, your formula gives $S_3=S_1+(2-1)(31\cdot 2-11)=52$, not $41$ as in the OP. Am I missing something?

Comment: Rand, you made a mistake in your last equation. 10(k-1)(2k-1) + (k-1)(11k-21) = (k-1)(20k - 10 + 11k - 21) = (k-1)(31k - 31). Also, i think you lost your n^2 which would be why your equation doesn't work.

Comment: @Ankoganit Should be working now.

Comment: I've been impressed from the start by how quickly you solved the pattern! The algebra is inevitably cluttered, admittedly, so in test-solving this I ran straight to the relatively lazy cubic form. Speaking of which, just what is that total for line 1,000,000?

Comment: (Dear rand al'thor, this could be yet another
$\color{#0c0}{\Large\raise-.1ex\checkmark} \!$ in your cap
if you copy line 1,000,000's total from
[the presumably-correct wiki answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49882/18129).)

Comment: @humn As you suggested, I copied it here, but my brain was well-rested and my memories not near, so I took you on trust and hoped that it works - check it you must, with your lovable quirks.

Comment: Thank you, rand al'thor!
(My pre-canned term $\sum_n$ in the wiki
 should've been renamed to follow your use of $S_n$ all along.
 Ah, regret$\varsigma$.)

Answer (score 1):

First, as pointed out by **rand al'thor**, the biggest digit $n$ should be always used as units digit. Then we add one of each smaller digit in front to create $n$ distinct numbers, so for $n=4$ we get

> 4  14  24  34

Then, we repeat the same procedure for $n-1$, but now only $n-2$ times, since one digit is already used. The procedure ends when we used all required digits. Putting it in a nice math formula:

$$S = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(n-i)(n-2i) + 10\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(\sum_{j=i}^{n-i}j)$$

The first part of the equation accounts for counting all the units, the second for tens.

This gives:

4:

> $4+14+24+34$ and $3+23 = 102$

5:

> $5+15+25+35+45$ and $4 + 24+34$ plus $3 = 190$

6:

> $6+16+26+36+46+56$ plus $5+25+35+45$ plus $4+34=334$

7:

> 518

8:

> 780

9:

> 1095

1000000:

> 1.4583e+018

Answer (score 1):

Wiki answer to illustrate and complete
[rand al'thor’s
 solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49265/18129):
 
An example of how terms of an even line
inductively build the terms of the next even line,
and a way to get line 1,000,000’s total by hand.

> ```
>          Terms of line 6                                      Terms of line 8
>      -----------------------                              -----------------------
>                                      all-new
>                                        row          8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78
>                                      ------->       '----'---:'---:'---:'----'----'----'
>                                                              :    :    :    |    |    |
>    6    16   26   36   46   56        +1 +1           7      27   37   47   57   67   |
>    '-----'----'----'----'----'        ----->          '-------'---:'---:'----'----'---'
>              :    :    |    |                                     :    :    |    |
>      5       25   35   45   |         +1 +1             6         36   46   56   |
>      '--------'----'----'---'         ----->            '----------'---:'----'---'
>                   :    |                                               :    |
>        4          34   |              +1 +1               5            45   |
>        '-----------'---'              ----->              '-------------'---'
>
>      (Smaller digits appear as columns only, larger digits follow rows as well)
> ```

**Getting the total of line $\boldsymbol n$ = 1,000,000** (by hand)

Call $\, \sum_n$ the cubic polynomial
for the total of line $n$, where $n$ is even,
and use constants $\small A,B,C,D\,$
in a way that makes them easy to work by hand.

$$\require{begingroup}\begingroup \small
\def \S       #1{ \llap{\textstyle \sum_{#1}} }
 \def \f    #1#2{ {\normalsize #1   \over \normalsize  #2} }
  \def \F   #1#2{ { \large     #1    \over \normalsize #2} }
   \def \PF #1#2{ {\large\raise -.3ex(} \kern-.1em \F{#1}{#2} \kern-.1em
                  { \large\raise-.3ex)} }
\small \begin{array}{rl}
           & \normalsize \S{n} \small = \kern-.8em
           &  \normalsize \rlap{ An(n{-}2)(n{-}4) + Bn(n{-}2) + Cn + D }
\\[3ex]
  0 ~ = ~~ & \S{0} = \kern-.8em
           & A(0)(-2)(-4) + B(0)(-2) + C(0) + D
           & \kern-0.5em = D
           & \Longrightarrow~~  D ~~~ = ~~~~ 0
\\[1.5ex]
 14 ~ = ~~ & \S{2} = \kern-.8em
           & A(2)(0)(-2) \,~ + \,\: B(2)(0) \,~ + ~ C(2)
           & \kern-1.0em = 2C
           & \Longrightarrow~~  C ~~ = ~~~~ \f{14}{2} ~~~~ = ~~ 7
\\[1.5ex]
102 ~ = ~~ & \S{4} = \kern-.8em
           & A(4)(2)(0) \;~~ + ~~ B(4)(2) ~~ + ~ 7(4)
           & \kern-1.5em = 8B + 28
           & \Longrightarrow~~  B ~ = ~~ \f{102{-}28}{8} ~~ = ~ \f{37}{4}
\\[1.5ex]
334 ~ = ~~ & \S{6} = \kern-.8em
           & A(6)(4)(2) ~~ + ~~\, \f{37}{4}(6)(4) ~ + ~ 7(6)
           & \kern-2.0em = 48A + 222 + 42 \kern-.5em
           & \Longrightarrow~~  A  =  \f{334{-}222{-}42}{48}  =  \f{35}{24}
\\[3ex]
           & \normalsize \llap{\Longrightarrow~~ \textstyle\sum_n} \small = \kern-.8em
           &  \normalsize \rlap{ \f {35}{24}n(n{-}2)(n{-}4) + \f  {37}{4} n(n{-}2) + 7n }
\\[1ex]    & \llap{} = \kern-.8em
           &  \rlap{ \f  {35}{24} n(n^2{-}6n{+}8) + \f{222}{24}n(n{-}2) + \f{168}{24}n }
\\[1ex]    & \llap{} = \kern-.8em
           &         \F {n}{24}     ( 35n^2 + 12n + 4 )
\\[1ex]    & \llap{} = \kern-.8em
           &           \F{n}{6} \big(  875 \PF{n}{10}^2 + 3n + 1 \big)
\\[3ex]
           & \normalsize \S{1,000,000} \small = \kern-.8em
           &        \f{10^6}{6} \big( 875(10^{10}) + 3(10^6) + 1 \big)
\\[1.5ex]  & \llap{} = \kern-.8em
           & \rlap{\large{8,750,003,000,001,000,000 \over 6}}
\\[1ex]    & \llap{} = \kern-.8em
           &   1,458,333,833,333,500,000
\end{array}\endgroup$$

This amounts to a line 1,000,000 with 250,000,500,000 terms.

> 1,000,000.   
>  **1,458,333,833,333,500,000**   =
>  
>  
>                   
>  [500,001] + [500,002] + [500,003] + **· · ·** + [1,000,000]
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  1[1,000,000]
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  2[999,999] + 2[1,000,000]
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  3[999,998] + 3[999,999] + 3[1,000,000]
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  **· · ·**
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  [500,000][500,001] + [500,000][500,002] + **· · ·**
>                          + [500,000][1,000,000]
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  **· · ·**
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  [999,997][999,998] + [999,997][999,999] + [999,997][1,000,000]
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  [999,998][999,999] + [999,998][1,000,000]
>  
>  
>                  
>    +  [999,999][1,000,000]

Comment: Note: The $\sum_n$ summation here
should've been labeled $S_n$ to follow
[rand al'thor's solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49265/18129).